# How to estimate False Discovery Rate from p-value distribution?

Tags: machine-learning, statistical-significance, p-value, model, false-discovery-rate

I have learned many models and I calculated p-values for the cross-validation errors. I want to select significant models based on the false discovery rate (FDR). How can I estimate the FDR from p-value distribution?

Comment: I strongly recommend looking at Andrew Gelman’s writings on this. Most statisticians would argue that the true false discovery rate is *always* 0%, because the null hypothesis is always false.

Comment: Why are you trying to estimate the false discovery rate? What’s your goal in your study? Are you trying to adjust for multiple comparisons?

Answer (score -1):

Generally speaking, the false discovery rate correction requires ranking your p-values and then computing a critical value (based on the false discovery rate) that you can compare to your p-values. This website gives a very concrete example: [here](https://www.statisticshowto.com/benjamini-hochberg-procedure/).

If you're using R, then it's even easier to do the adjustment. The following code is a quick example:

```
pvals <- c(0.04, 0.03, 0.06, 0.01, 0.02, 0.003)
p.adjust(p = pvals, method = "BH")
```

In the above code, the object `pvals` is a list of the p-values that you obtained from your analyses. The function `p.adjust` provides several different options for adjusting p-values based on multiple observations. In this case, the false discovery rate adjustment can be done by specifying `method = "BH"` for Benjamin-Hochberg or `method = "fdr"` for false discovery rate (note: they are the exact same procedure and will give the exact same results).