# Calculate fraction of multiple tests for which the null hypothesis was rejected

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, nonparametric, multiple-comparisons, false-discovery-rate

Consider a test (e.g., a permutation test) that tests, at the individual level, if a binary event occured or not.

- A paper that I was recently reading, for example, tested whether or not a pair of two students cheated in a multiple-choice exam (plagiarism).
- They then run such a test for every pair of students, and reject the null hypothesis for $10\%$ of all pairs.
- They then concluded that $10\%$ of all pairs cheated.

Now, I am wondering if this conclusion makes sense. For each single test, there is a certain probability that the authors identified a false positive (they chose a $5\%$ significance level). Shouldn't this imply that $5\%$ of the pairs for which the null hypothesis (no cheating) was rejected should be false positives? Can I then conclude that the share of cheaters should be by $5\%$ lower.

More generally, I wonder whether it ever makes sense to calculate the fraction for which the $H_0$ is rejected. Shouldn't I, at least, account for multiple testing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case one should definitely account for multiple testing. I think this is a case for use of FDR (False Discovery Rates), see [false-discovery-rate](/questions/tagged/false-discovery-rate).  You should want to control that you **do not accuse too many non-cheaters of cheating**.  See [FPR (false positive rate) vs FDR (false discovery rate)](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/336455/fpr-false-positive-rate-vs-fdr-false-discovery-rate)  or  [How to estimate False Discovery Rate from p-value distribution?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/89847/how-to-estimate-false-discovery-rate-from-p-value-distribution).

I learned about this ideas first from [this paper by Brad Efron](http://statweb.stanford.edu/%7Eckirby/brad/papers/2005LocalFDR.pdf).